# Функция alert_is_present() и switch_to_alert()

Tags: python, selenium

Есть такой код:

```
# Alert start
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
self.driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
# Alert end
```

Первая строчка - проверяет всплывающее окно на наличие.
Вторая строчка - нажимает на кнопку [Cancel].

Я хочу создать 2 функции, а потом, вызывать их при необходимости.
Ещё не разобрался с возвратами и т.д., подскажите:

```
def alertIsPresent(self, timeout=10):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())

def alertDismiss(self):
    alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.dismiss()
```

Вызываю я функцию так:

```
PageObject.alertIsPresent()
PageObject.alertDismiss()
```

Но последняя скобка подчёркнута, и написано, что должен быть `self`.

Чувствую что-то не правильно.

Comment: `self` нужен, если вы пишите какой-то класс; если у вас нет класса, то уберите `self` из списка аргументов методов.

Comment: У меня эти функции находятся внутри класса `class PageObject:` по этому я и использовал `self`

Comment: Внимательно проверьте отступы, возможно проблема в этом. Если с ними всё в порядке, то можете привести полный код?

Comment: Да, отступы верны. Может при вызове функции надо какой-то параметр передавать? т.к. постоянно вызов функции требует `self` код большой, сюда не помещается...

Answer (score 0):

Объявите экземпляр класса и вызывайте эти методы из него:

```
page_obj = PageObject(driver=..., xpathlocator=...)

page_obj.alertIsPresent()
page_obj.alertDismiss()
```

Comment: Я в начале сделал испорт: `from utils import PageObject` по этому подумал, что нет необходимости объявлять его повнторно. Хотя может мои знаничя в этом минимальные. В вашем случае `page_obj = PageObject(...)` просит `driver` и `xpathlocator`, хотя функция использует только драйвер браузера...

Comment: Импорт лишь делает возможным использовать класс в другом модуле. Поэтому вам всё ещё нужно при создании экземпляра указывать обязательные аргументы, которые вы прописали в методе инициализации `__init__`. В вашем случае получается это `driver` и `xpathlocator`.

Comment: Да, в классе прописано: `class PageObject:

    def __init__(self, driver, xpathLocator):
        self.driver = driver
        self.locator = xpathLocator
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)`

Comment: Вам эти параметры и надо передать при создании экземпляра. Если какие-то параметры необязательны, вы можете указать это в методе `__init__` передав этому параметру какое-нибудь значение по умолчанию, например, `None`. Всё вместе `def __init__(self, driver, xpathlocator=None)`.